# PowerShell to Remove ADGroup from Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
start-transcript -path c:\docs\MyTranscript.txt

$WhenChangedDate = ((get-date).addmonths(-12)) #has not been modified in over a year

$domain = "Domain1"

$emptygroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties members, whenchanged -server $domain|  Where-Object {($_.members.count -eq 0) -and ($_.whenchanged -le $WhenChangedDate)} | Select-Object -last 10

#$emptygroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties members, whenchanged -server $domain | Where-Object { ($_.members.count -eq 0) -and ($_.whenchanged -le $WhenChangedDate) -and ($_.name -notlike '*CTX*')} | Select-Object -last 10

$emptygroups.name | %{REmove-adgroup $_ -Confirm:$false -WhatIf}

Stop-transcript
```

I'm getting the below error for Domain1. However, it runs successfully on Domain2. Any ideas?

```
Remove-ADGroup : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again. At line:1 char:38
+ $emptygroups.name | %{REmove-adgroup $_ -Confirm:$false -WhatIf}
+                                      ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-ADGroup], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.
   Commands.RemoveADGroup
```

Comment: [1] what does the problem have to do with `job-scheduling`? ///// [2] PLEASE, remove the commented out code and any other lines that DO NOT pertain to your Question. ///// [3] have you confirmed that the `domain1` result contains any items? have you confirmed that the result contains valid values?

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say that there are no empty groups to delete.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do can be accomplished using the following `LDAPFilter`:

```
"(&(!member=*)(whenChanged<=$date)(!name=*CTX*))"
```

- `&` All conditions must be met.
- `!member=*` Group without members.
- `whenChanged<=$date` **WhenChanged** lower than a specified date.
- `!name=*CTX*` Name **not like** CTX.

---

```
$domain = "Domain1"
$date = [datetime]::Today.AddYears(-1).ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss.sZ')

Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(&(!member=*)(whenChanged<=$date)(!name=*CTX*))" -Server $domain |
Select-Object -Last 10 |
Remove-ADGroup -Confirm:$false -WhatIf
```